# Querying Mapped Superclasses or Equivalent

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, inheritance, jpa, jpql

I have three classes that are subclasses of the abstract superclass Automobile. I'm using the single table inheritance model and a `@MappedSuperclass` for the automobile class. The subclasses are Car, Truck, and Van.

I want to query the automobile class, but have the different subclasses returned. I've written a couple queries and done some research, but it seems like it is not possible to query against MappedSuperclasses. I have also tried to do NativeSqlQueries, but I can't seem to be able to figure out how to specifiy multiple ResultSetMappings.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Please show your query and the mappings, chances are there's a small mistake somewhere that prevents you from getting the right behavior.

Comment: The query that I want is SELECT a FROM Automobile a WHERE a.year < 1998. And the different subclasses just extend the superclass.

Comment: Some JPA implementations allow querying of mapped superclasses, but as the answer says, the spec doesn't require it. Maybe your JPA impl isn't so flexible

Comment: I'm using eclipselink 2.5. I've learned it doesn't allow to query on mapped super classes but it does allow querying on regular entity super classes. I ended up switching from TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance model to JOINED model. Now I can query on the superclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a mapped-superclass in the query. If you want to use `Automobile` in the query, don't mark it as mapped-superclass, instead mark it as an entity.

Following is from the [JPA 2.0 Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/), second paragraph is what's relevant in your case -

> **2.11.2 Mapped Superclasses**
>
> An entity may inherit from a superclass that provides persistent entity state and mapping information, but which is not itself an entity. Typically, the purpose of such a mapped superclass is to define state and mapping information that is common to multiple entity classes.
>
> **A mapped superclass, unlike an entity, is not queryable and must not be passed as an argument to EntityManager or Query operations.** Persistent relationships defined by a mapped superclass must
> be unidirectional.

Comment: Is it as simple as changing the mappedsuperclass annotation to an entity annotation?

Comment: IMO, it should be according to what the specification says.